# Why we have two classes for JWT tokens JwtSecurityTokenHandler vs JsonWebTokenHandler?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt

Its always confusing and there is no mention about which is the better one to use, I personally prefer JsonWebTokenHandler as it is more appropriate return type of ValidateToken

The difference in namespace is Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens vs System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, which is also quite similar?

Any guidelines available ?

Answer (score 13):

JsonWebTokenHandler is the new and improved vesion.

See: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/945

brentschmaltz wrote:

> JwtSecurityTokenHandler was modeled after the existing System.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenHandler. There were some compromises that we had to make, such as using System.Security.ClaimsIdentity as the type to build the JWS or JWE when using SecurityTokenDescriptor. ValidateToken had an out parameter of type SecurityToken, which doesn't for async.
>   A ClaimsPrincipal was returned, sometimes using claim type mapping to build the claims.
>   This model new model, is much lighter weight and works with native Json.Net objects.
>   We plan on layering on top, so that you can get back to the existing types, but we will allow users to control what is returned using injection and delegates.
>
> We saw performance improvements of up to 100% in some scenarios.

Comment: Also, on the [wiki page for the project](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/wiki), it's clearly stated that `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.JsonWebTokens` "is a newer, faster version of `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` that has additional functionality."

Comment: Is there any migration documentation?